# Probability of choosing a number from the set $\{1,2,\ldots,99\}$ that divided by $5$ has the remainder $2$ and is a multiple of $3$

Tags: probability, elementary-number-theory, chinese-remainder-theorem

Good evening to everyone. I have to find the probability of choosing a number  from the set {1,2...99} that divided by 5 has the remainder 2 and at the same time it's multiple of 3. I know that the probability of an event is the ratio of the number of observations of the event to the total numbers of the observations.The number of observations of the event is $6$ $(17, 32, 47, 62, 77, 92)$ therefore $ \frac{6}{99} = \frac{2}{33}  $. But my friend told me that I didn't solve it correctly. How do I solve this problem? Thanks for any response.

Comment: Is $17$ a multiple of three?  Are any of those multiples of three?  You seem to have found the elements which have remainder two when divided by five *and remainder two when divided by three*, not those elements which have remainder two when divided by five *which are also multiples of three (i.e. remainder ZERO when divided by three)*

Comment: @JMoravitz thanks for the clarification

Comment: You can approach via chinese remainder theorem (or by simply spotting the pattern) to see that the numbers which satisfy $\begin{cases}x\equiv 2\pmod{5}\\ x\equiv 0\pmod{3}\end{cases}$ are those numbers which are $x\equiv 12\pmod{15}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final answer is correct, but you didn't obtain it correctly.

For a number to have remainder $2$ when divisible by $5$, it must end in a $2$ or a $7$. Of the numbers $2, 7, 12, 17, 22, 27, 32, 37, 42, 47, 52, 57, 62, 67, 72, 77, 82, 87, 92, 97$, which are divisible by $3$? Only those whose digits add up to a multiple of $3$. Namely, $12, 27, 42, 57, 72, 87$. Thus, there are $6$, so the probability is $6/99=2/33$.